# Dart generate 1 file base on all annotations

Tags: flutter, dart, annotations

Is there a way to use build_runner & source_gen for annotation processing but only generate 1 file instead of generating a .g.dart file for each file that uses my annotation? Or is this something I should do manually with a simple dart program?

for example:

```
//File test1.dart
@GenerateThis
class Test1 {
}
```

```
//File test2.dart
@GenerateThis
class Test2 {
}
```

```
//File test3.dart
@GenerateThis
class Test3 {
}
```

GENERATED FILE IN THE ROOT

```
/** GENEREATED FILE **/
@GenerateThis -> test1.dart
@GenerateThis -> test2.dart
@GenerateThis -> test3.dart
```

Comment: You can try this program. https://pub.dev/packages/yaml2podo. It generates 1 file.

Comment: This generates 1 file from a yaml file. I want to use annotations.